# How to access a remote Elasticsearch server (ON Google Compute Engine) from my local computer

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I have spent 2 days and searched a lot on stackoverflow and many forums but am not able to make it work and still confused. I will keep things simple.

i m using a ElasticSearch for database of my Laravel (a PHP Framework) WEB Application as a backend.

Elasticsearch is deployed on Google compute engine instance  i.e UBUNTU 16.0 LTS server.

i want make RESTful request from my laptop to elasticsearch throughout the development. (i know i can install elasticsearch locally but thats not the problem)

which means that from my ubuntu server's Ssh cli, when i do `'curl -X GET localhost:9200'` it perfectly responds that elasticsearch is running. i.e

```
{
"name" : "T1Xfr06",
"cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
"cluster_uuid" : "NqdJol0ZQ6imGOZxIVvnNA",
"version" : {
"number" : "6.3.0",
"build_flavor" : "default",
"build_type" : "deb",
"build_hash" : "424e937",
"build_date" : "2018-06-11T23:38:03.357887Z",
"build_snapshot" : false,
"lucene_version" : "7.3.1",
"minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "5.6.0",
"minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "5.0.0"
},
"tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

but i want to do from my laptop `curl -X GET
 'http://MY_Server's_PUblic_IP:9200'` but it does not responds.

here is what i have tried to make it work.

1. IN `sudo nano /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml` ,   i changed network.host like `network.host: 0.0.0.0` and then `sudo systemctl restart elasticsearch` which has been told everywhere that allows traffic form all IP addresses , but that does not respond to my laptops curl request still!
2. i have checked and disabled any ufw firewall settings my `sudo ufw 
   status` is `Status: inactive`
   (That mean every ip address is allowed to connect right?)
3. Just to check that my `curl -X GET 'http://MY_Server's_PUblic_IP:9200'` is a legitimate thing to do. i installed nginx on my UBUNTU server and then did `curl -X GET 'http://MY_Server's_PUblic_IP:80'` from my laptop . and it responds straightway!

After all this when i do `$ curl -X GET 'http://35.237.107.165:9200'` from my laptop, the response is `curl: (7) Failed to connect to 35.237.107.165 port 9200: Timed out`

I am a beginner and i know there is a lot in elasticsearch that i do not know about. what am i missing ? why i can't access elasticsearch installed on a server over `http` from my local computer? i have no firewall settings at all.

> Update: why there is no network.bind_host parameter in my yml file ?

```
#---------------------------------- Cluster -----------------------------------
#Use a descriptive name for your cluster:
#
#cluster.name: my-application
#
# ------------------------------------ Node ------------------------------------
#
# Use a descriptive name for the node:
#
#node.name: node-1
#
# Add custom attributes to the node:
#
#node.attr.rack: r1
#
# ----------------------------------- Paths ------------------------------------
#
# Path to directory where to store the data (separate multiple locations by comma):
#
path.data: /var/lib/elasticsearch
#
# Path to log files:
#
path.logs: /var/log/elasticsearch
#
# ----------------------------------- Memory -----------------------------------
#
# Lock the memory on startup:
#
#bootstrap.memory_lock: true
#
# Make sure that the heap size is set to about half the memory available
# on the system and that the owner of the process is allowed to use this
# limit.
#
# Elasticsearch performs poorly when the system is swapping the memory.
#
# ---------------------------------- Network -----------------------------------
#
# Set the bind address to a specific IP (IPv4 or IPv6):
#
network.host: 0.0.0.0
#
# Set a custom port for HTTP:
#
http.port: 8080
#
# For more information, consult the network module documentation.
#
# --------------------------------- Discovery ----------------------------------
# Pass an initial list of hosts to perform discovery when new node is started:
# The default list of hosts is ["127.0.0.1", "[::1]"]
#
#discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["35.237.107.165"]
#
# Prevent the "split brain" by configuring the majority of nodes (total number of master-eligible nodes / 2 + 1):
#
#discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes:
#
# For more information, consult the zen discovery module documentation.
#
# ---------------------------------- Gateway -----------------------------------
#
# Block initial recovery after a full cluster restart until N nodes are started:
#
#gateway.recover_after_nodes: 3
#
# For more information, consult the gateway module documentation.
#
# ---------------------------------- Various -----------------------------------
# Require explicit names when deleting indices:
#action.destructive_requires_name: true
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your port number in the elasticsearch.yml file in the line 'http.port:' (In the elasticsearch.yml file by default these fields are commented you need remove '#' to uncomment). then restart elasticsearch and try to access new port. better if you can share elasticsearch.yml file.

As i have experienced as soon as you have change the host you need to do Enable Memory Locking otherwise it will throws error.

check the 'Enable Memory Locking' part of the following document to Enable Memory Locking

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-production-elasticsearch-cluster-on-ubuntu-14-04

thank you

Comment: Hey @upuna thanks for the awnser. i changed the port to 8800, 8080 & others & did what is been told in the above article & restarted elasticsearch, it still responds to `curl localhost:8800` but when `curl 'http://MY_SERVER_IP:8800` its still the same. `curl: (7) Failed to connect to 35.231.57.211 port 8800: Timed out`. what do i do ?

Comment: change network bind host as follows and see network.bind_host: 0.0.0.0

Comment: brother i have updated my post . plz take a look at elasticsearch.yml file. there is no "network.bind_host" parameter in it. do i have to add it myself ?

Comment: In order to access es server remotely you need to set 'network.host' to your server ip address like network.host: 35.237.107.165. you can add network.bind_host by yourself. sorry for the late reply..